# Remove terms in a DocumentTermMatrix that appear in ALL documents

Tags: r

I am using DocumentTermMatrix as follows:

```
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,
                         control = list(
                                        #weighting = weightTfIdf,
                                        stopwords = TRUE, 
                                        wordLengths=c(3, 10),
                                        removePunctuation = T,
                                        removeNumbers = T,
                                        stemming = T))
```

How do I remove terms that appear ALL documents from the dtm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No minimal example but this should work:

```
library(slam)
dtm[slam::col_sums(dtm > 0) != nrow(dtm), ]
```

Comment: Tyler, I am not following your answer. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I used `x` instead of  `dtm` (this is why it is important to make your question reproducible which yours is not since no minimal data set is provided).  I replaced `x` for `dtm` in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the accepted answer should be changed to the following:

```
library(slam)
dtm[, slam::col_sums(dtm > 0) != nrow(dtm)]
```

Because it is '''document X term'''. 
And you end up documents with no terms in it, use the following code:

```
dtm[slam::row_sums(dtm > 0) > 0, ]
```

Then LDA will not give you an error that at least one of the column for each document should have a non-zero value.